# Any ideas about how to get rid of self?

Tags: python, self

Is there anyway of making Python methods have access to the class fields/methods without using the self parameter?

It's really annoying having to write self. self. self. self. The code gets so ugly to the point I'm thinking of not using classes anymore purely for code aesthetics. I don't care about the risks or best practices. I just want not to see self anymore.

P.S. I know about the renaming possibility but it's not the point.

Comment: _Any ideas about how to get rid of self?_ - sounds funny

Comment: How will your instances know what they're operating on?

Comment: you could name the parameter `s`, `other` or `not_self`. :-p

Comment: It's a dynamic language. How hard is it to search for a method/variable in the class scope?

Comment: @C2H5OH I feel a new PEP coming on...

Comment: @Will my comment was removed due to obscenity I guess :-(

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Have you looked at horribly ugly `locals()` hacks?

Comment: How would you assign values to attributes on `self` without explicit `self`?

Comment: Well, I guess it will have to be something like when you declare them you would have to write self, but when you use them (99% of time) you would just forget the self part. I mean... who would wanna use the same name as a field in a local method variable?

Comment: But you don't declare attributes in Python... or are you thinking of something else?

Comment: I don't know if "declare" is the right word but when you write in the class scope attribute = 1, I consider that declaring. When you use them as self.attribute in the methods I would like not to use self anymore. If would be possible to implement this in Python that's how I would do it. Maybe I care to much about how the code looks...

Comment: I've never had this problem; I'll refer to an instance attribute a couple of times in most methods, rarely more. If you're accessing a _lot_ of instance variables, perhaps you should be storing them in some data structure which you access once (e.g. a dict of options)?

Comment: Well it depends what you understand by couple of times. Even once is to much for me. I prefer to see context[context_key] = {} instead of self.context[self.context_key] = {}

Comment: But the problem with `attribute = 1` in class scope is that this doesn't declare an instance attribute -- it declares a class attribute, which is different.  Instance attributes in Python *are not declared statically,* they are *dynamic.*

Comment: This python aspect is really annoying. A bounty to get around this should be linked to this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. You could though use another word instead of self, although the convention is to use "self".

Answer (score 5):

This blog by Guido explains why it's here to stay:
http://neopythonic.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

Comment: I don't care why it has to stay. I want it gone :))

Comment: @AlBundy I think you'd have to look at another language then. It's as ingrained as whitespace denoting a block of code

Comment: I like Python especially for the whitespace blocking. I like writing less code. Less is by default more clear. I mean looking at a method and seeing self every two words... I don't know.

Comment: The linked blog doesn't address this at all; it's talking about removing `self` from parameter lists and making it a keyword; even if that happened, the actual method code would still be loaded with the `self`s OP dreads, and then you wouldn't even be able to use a different name.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible solution (except for making your own `no-self` Python version (using sources))
**Try another language.**